# Auto layout messed up after upgraded to XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a very simple application I created in XCode 5, it has a couple of labels, a table view and a couple of buttons and it uses auto layout which means everything is constrained.  I recently updated XCode to 6.2 and when I open this application and add an extra button for some reason it mess-ups some of the constrain views, even if I delete the newly added button the layout doesn’t go back and it looks bad, in fact I can revert back to previous Git versions and the layout doesn’t get fixed. I’m not looking for a solution I just want to know if someone else has seen a similar behavior when updating to a new XCode version.

Have anyone seen this behavior before?

FYI – I haven’t try open the app with an older XCode version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i had the same issue. i just removed all auto layout and used auto resizing to all my view individually. It worked for me.

Comment: Cool, I will look into auto re-sizing.